# How to install macports -devel port not listed in the search?

Tags: python, port, macports

I'd like to install this https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30450 devel port, called "py27-wxpython-devel".

However, when I do:

```
sudo port install py27-wxpython-devel
```

I get:

```
Error: Port py27-wxpython-devel not found
```

I understand, that there is no such port in the available ports list here — http://www.macports.org/ports.php, but people in the ticket successfully installed it some how.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your own local repository and put all the files there. Full instructions are [here](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/development.local-repositories.html).